# Putting long text string into textviews

Tags: android

In every new version of my app I like to put a What's New section which is basically a long(-ish) text that tends to have a lot of apostrophes and percentage signs and newlines and what have you.

Is there some easier way of loading it in a textview other than escaping all the problematic characters and replacing newlines with `\n` or `<br />`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the text as a `Raw` text file in `resource folder` and read it

```
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.share);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And then set to `TextView`

```
textView.setText(text.toString());
```